# LinQ groupby multiply columns and sum c#

Tags: c#, html, linq, list, foreach

i have a list of items in c# like this:

```
Rid         Pdv     Total  Quantity
DESAYUNOS   VITP    55        1
CENAS       REST    38        2
COMIDAS     VITP    23        3
DESAYUNOS   REST    116       7
CENAS       VITP    112       1
COMIDAS     REST    11        4
DESAYUNOS   VITP    67        9
CENAS       REST    20        2
COMIDAS     VITP    47        5
DESAYUNOS   REST    5         2
CENAS       VITP    10        1
```

I want to get a result in wich the Quantity is multiply by the Total and by that sum all totals for all diferent "Pdv" and "Rid", im using a GroupBy but it only sums the Total on each diferent "Rid" and "Pdv"

```
@foreach (var item in Model.GroupBy(l => l.Rid)
    .Select(z => new 
                    { 
                        Turno = z.Key, 
                        Total = z.Sum(l => l.Total) 
                    }))
{
   <input value="@item" />
}
```

How can i make it "Total" multiply the "Quantity" before Sum's up?

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model
                     .Select(x => new //here you count your total
                     { 
                         Rid = x.Rid, 
                         Total = x.Total * x.Quantity
                     })
                     .GroupBy(l => l.Rid) //and then grouping
                     .Select(z => new 
                     { 
                         Turno = z.Key, 
                         Total = z.Sum(l => l.Total) 
                     }))
{
   <input value="@item" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I want to get a result in wich the Quantity is multiply by the Total and by that sum all totals for all diferent "**Pdv**" and "**Rid**"*

```
@foreach (var item in Model
                     .Select(m => new { Rid = m.Rid, m.Pdv, Total =m.Total * m.Quantity})
                     .GroupBy(g => new { g.Rid, g.Pdv} )
                     .Select(s => new 
                     { 
                         Rid = s.Key.Rid, 
                         Pdv = s.Key.Pdv, 
                         Total = s.Sum(t => t.Total) 
                     }))
{
   <input value="@item" />
}
```