# C#: LINQ query grouping by multiple columns in data table using Field method

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to get sum of t & kg grouping by year and unit.
Having problems getting it done in Linq using Field method. However. I'm able to do that without using the Field method.

The data in the data table is in below format.

```
Unit  Quantity  Year
 "t"    "10"    2019
 "t"    "05"    2018
 "kg"   "05"    2018
 "t"    "02"    2019
 "kg"   "14"    2018
 "kg"   "28"    2019
```

And the result should be this;

Result

```
 Total 2018 in kg - 19 
 Total 2018 in t  - 05
 Total 2019 in kg - 28
 Total 2019 in t  - 12
```

Here's all I have right now, it's grouping by all 3 columns as I mentioned in a group by statement. But, if I don't then I won't be able to access that column in the select statement.

Code snippet

**Note**: I don't have model property structure.

```
DataTable Dt = dsData.Tables["Data2019"];

 var data = from mfRecords in Dt.AsEnumerable()
        group mfRecords by new
        {
         DataUnit = mfRecords.Field<string>("Unit").ToString(),
         Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(mfRecords.Field<string>("Qty")),
         RecordYear = Convert.ToDateTime(mfRecords.Field<string>("SalesDate")).Year,
        } into g
        select new
         {
          SalesYear = g.Key.RecordYear,
          SalesUnit = g.Key.DataUnit,  
          TotalQty = g.Sum(k => g.Key.Quantity)
         };
```

This is done by using LINQ

```
var data = lst.Select(k => new { k.SalesDate.Year, k.Qty, k.Unit })
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Year,x.Unit }, (key, group) => new
            {
                SalesYear =  key.Year,
                SalesUnit = key.Unit,
                TotalQty = string.Format("{0:0.00}",group.Sum(k => k.Qty))
            })            
            .ToList();
```

Does anyone know how I can group by with Field method using LINQ?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: The `TotalQty` should not be in the grouping.  The `GroupBy` should only contain the properties that apply to grouping.  Add a `.Select()` afterwards to get the results... **[Check this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355564/linq-groupby-multiply-columns-and-sum-c-sharp)**

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Take a look at data table (Unit, Quantity, Year), I want to sum of Quantity by a grouping of Unit and Year(see the result table).

Comment: @Archer Yes, you right. But then how do we get "TotalQty" selected?

Comment: With a `.Select()` with a sum inside it - the link I gave you shows an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go like this instead:

```
 var data = from mfRecords in Dt.AsEnumerable()
            group mfRecords by new
            {
             DataUnit = mfRecords.Field<string>("Unit").ToString(),
             RecordYear = mfRecords.Field<string>("SalesDate")
            } into g
            select new
             {
              SalesYear = g.Key.RecordYear,
              SalesUnit = g.Key.DataUnit,  
              TotalQty = g.Sum(k => int.Parse((string)k["Qty"]))
             };
```

Explanation: You do not need to group by Quantity, because that is what you want to sum.